# Unable to successfully upgrade to new GPU: new card doesn't activate, screen stays black, apart from 'A2'

Tags: boot, nvidia-geforce

I am trying to replace my old Nvidia graphics card (GTX 570) with a new one (RTX 2060).

However, in the process, I am not able to properly activate the new card:

- The only thing in common to the old card, is the initial 'B4' and 'A2' digits that are displayed in the bottom right corner for the first few seconds (B4 initially, then A2)
- It does not even flash the logo of the motherboard (like the old card does)
- It is unable to even display the BIOS setup (I can't get into the BIOS, or I merely can't see it)
- It never even gets to the grub menu

After a while, the motherboard gives a single beep while the 'A2' continues displaying. Thereafter, the motherboard beeps every minute or so.

The GPU does power up, because its fans rotate (although not fast, as it's not displaying much).

When I remove the new card and plug the old card back in, it boots up fine and I am able to go into Ubuntu again, no beeps. The display is not what it should be because I followed various procedures of deleting drivers or disabling the nouveau driver.

I'm not sure whether the black screen is necessarily caused by the Ubuntu driver or possibly even something more problematic, e.g. the RAM. I say this because it never displays the GRUB menu, and I read somewhere that a single beep from the motherboard could indicate hardware problems like RAM, etc. However, that does not make sense, as the old card boots up fine.

Or could it be a dud GPU card?

My PC specs:

- i7 CPU
- 16GB RAM
- 1X SSD and 2X HDs

I recently did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04, so it won't be a problem if I need to re-install it. I am an eager user of Ubuntu, but not a guru by any means.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated, as I am at wit's end!

Comment: after reinstalling did you choose in Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers -> Using Nvidia driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-440 (propriertary, tested) ?

Comment: kannzzmm2: do you mean after inserting the new card and booting up? If so: I can't get to a screen that allows me to do that, because the screen is black. I tried to install the new driver via command line with the old card still inserted (that way I am able to SEE something at least), but it does not want to upgrade, because it says the driver is incompatible with the card. With the new card, I am not even able to open a terminal :-(

Comment: i mean after reinstalling ubuntu.. the best way would be to backup all your files, remove the old card, insert the new graphic card, boot with Ubuntu Live and try if it works. If you choose safe graphics from the installer and if the screen is black again then reboot and within the boot menu press e to add nomodeset at the config file.. see this for more https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/

Comment: also check this https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it